# Citation/bib style with biblatex

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex

I start diving into `biblatex` to handle my sources.

At the moment I am using the `style=alphabetic`. But for the `cite` command inside the text, I would like to have an output like `[Smith 2005]`. The bibliography should also show this key `[Smith 2005]`, like it happens with the alphabetic style.

Is there already something appropriate style or do I need to do some tweaks?

--- EDIT 1 ---

Additionally to the customizations already made for the `authoryear` style, I would like to added the following

1. For better reading, the entries in the bibliography should have a small indent after the first line (EDIT: Please ignore it, it is caused by the option `parskip=half` of the used document class `scrbook`)
2. Editors should also be listed with last name, first name. For authors this I do with `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`
3. Repeating authors should not be replaced by a --- in the bibliography.

My present configuration for biblatex is as follow:

```
    \RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book with a very very very very very long title},
year={2005},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}

@book{smith2,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book2},
year={2006},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}

@incollection{Grasso2010,
    location = {New York},
    Author = {Grasso, D. and Burkins, M. D.},
    Booktitle = {Holistic Engineering Education -- Beyond Technology},
    Editor = {Grasso, D. and Burkins, M. D.},
    Pages = {1-10},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Beyond Technology: The Holistic Advantage},
    Year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,%
    backend=biber,%
    language=english,%
    backref=true,%
    maxcitenames=1,%
    maxbibnames=99,
    doi=true
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1em}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\begin{document}
\cite{smith1} \cite{smith2} \cite{Grasso2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your support.
Christian

Comment: Do you have two bib-entries to test? And what do you mean with the small indention? (point 1) -- the code above doesn't show the result you wanted?

Comment: Re point 3: Use the package option `dashed=false`.

Comment: @ChrisP: I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

Now I provide only the example.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book with a very very very very very long title},
year={2005},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}

@book{smith2,
author={John Smith and Mike Someone},
title={The book2},
year={2006},
location={New York},
publisher={Publisher},
}

@incollection{Grasso2010,
    location = {New York},
    Author = {Grasso, D. and Burkins, M. D.},
    Booktitle = {Holistic Engineering Education -- Beyond Technology},
    Editor = {Grasso, D. and Burkins, M. D.},
    Pages = {1-10},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {Beyond Technology: The Holistic Advantage},
    Year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,%
    backend=biber,%
    language=english,%
    backref=true,%
    maxcitenames=1,%
    maxbibnames=99,
    doi=true,
    dashed=false
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1em}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}

\begin{document}
\cite{smith1} \cite{smith2} \cite{Grasso2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marco! I added some of your ideas to my code to improve the way sources are referenced. I would like to do some further customizations, which I will ask below.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the bibliography styles you are after are `cell`, `apalike` or `apasoft`.  For other bibliography styles that might be useful, have a look at the following link.

http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html

For biblatex, I believe the bibliography style that you are after is `apa`.  For other bibliography styles that might be useful, have a look at the following link.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib

Comment: The linked site is for traditional BibTeX styles, not for `biblatex`.